# No Content-Length field in the HTTP response header (google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

Content-Length header is missing when I try to download rar, exe, msi static files, though response for images contains Content-Length, but if I change rar extension to jpg it **doesn't**.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What headers *do* you see? It's possible it's being served using Transfer-Encoding: Chunked, which is a perfectly legitimate way of transferring responses over HTTP.

Also, how are you serving the file - using static files, your code, or the blobstore?

Comment: You are right, it was about static files and Transfer-Encoding: Chunked. After creating a script for serving files, everything worked out and now Content-Length header is sent to the client.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried serving a copy of http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/GoogleAppEngine_1.3.4.msi as a [static file](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers)and experienced the same issue - GAE's response did not include a `Content-Length` header.

*Workaround*: If the `Content-Length` header is critical, then consider hosting your static msi (etc.) file types on a file hosting site (e.g., [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for now.

**Edit**: This is the intended behavior after all - Nick points out that the files are being transferred with the `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` header.