# App Engine: Is it possible to disable Transfer-Encoding: Chunked for large static files?

Tags: google-app-engine, preloader, chunked-encoding

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029929/no-content-length-field-in-the-http-response-header-google-app-engine), is it possible to disable the "Transfer-Encoding: Chunked" method for large static files, therefore forcing a Content-Length to be returned instead?

My site serves a few Flash files. The small ones (500-700kb) report a Content-Length fine, but the large one (approx 3MB) doesn't, instead using chunked mode.

Although the file downloads fine, the Flash preloader doesn't work, because it can't tell how long the file is, and therefore what percentage is loaded.

Is my only option to write a dynamic handler to serve the static file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transfer-Encoding is in the list of Disallowed HTTP Response Headers (modifying them has no effect). [source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/responseclass.html#Disallowed_HTTP_Response_Headers)